# sessionScope HashMap & checkboxes

Tags: javascript, ajax, xpages

**PROBLEM**

I'm having serious issue (maybe its more of an understanding issue?) where sessionScope just doesn't want to cooperate with me? Here is the thing:

- my website has alot of checboxes. when clicking one, ajax call is used to just store checbox info into sessionScope hashmap. This works.
- if you uncheck checkbox, ajax call is made again, this time, it removes the entry from sessionScrope hashmap. This works.
- checking and unchecking works as charm since i'm listing hashmap after every ajax call to see the debug info.

Now... if i refresh my main site with checkboxes, another javascript is taking sessionScope hashmap and check checkboxes that are stored in sessionScope hashmap. Pretty self explanatory, right?

Well, after I refresh the site, it looks like as the page takes PREVIOUS sessionScope HashMap (meaning the one, before I refreshed the page).  But, it doesn't end here. After 2nd refresh, it shows the correct result. After 3rd refresh, it shows the previous HashMap state and so it stays. :|

Am I missing something here? And as soon as I refresh, HashMap is now from previous state without writing anything to it, just reading it.

How is this possible?

Please help me out understand this thing because I have no idea what is going on...

best regards,

Gregor

**UPDATE (the code):**

checkboxes page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/gama.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="#{javascript:ROOT_PATH}/js/jquery-ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script src="/global.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
        <xp:script src="#{javascript:ROOT_PATH}/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script
            src="#{javascript:ROOT_PATH}/js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script src="#{javascript:ROOT_PATH}/gama.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>


    <xp:this.data>

        <xp:dominoView var="view1" databaseName="***HIDDEN***.nsf"
            viewName="dflt">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:table style="width:80.0%" border="1">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td
                style="width:100.0px;border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;" valign="top"
                styleClass="xspPanelViewColumnHeader">
                <xp:br></xp:br>
                10.5.*
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td valign="top"
                style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;width:auto">
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.33" id="checkBox3"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.34" id="checkBox4"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.35" id="checkBox5"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.38" id="checkBox6"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.39" id="checkBox7"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.40" id="checkBox8"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:br></xp:br>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.49" id="checkBox9"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.50" id="checkBox10"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.51" id="checkBox11"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.54" id="checkBox12"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.55" id="checkBox13"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.5.56" id="checkBox14"></xp:checkBox>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td styleClass="xspPanelViewColumnHeader" valign="top"
                style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                10.6.*
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                <xp:checkBox text="10.6.32" id="checkBox15"></xp:checkBox>

            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td styleClass="xspPanelViewColumnHeader"
                style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                192.*
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">

            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td styleClass="xspPanelViewColumnHeader"
                style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                193.*
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">

            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td styleClass="xspPanelViewColumnHeader"
                style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">
                10.21.*
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;">


                <xp:checkBox text="10.21.8" id="checkBox2"></xp:checkBox>
                <xp:checkBox text="10.21.12" id="checkBox1"></xp:checkBox>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td styleClass="xspPanelViewColumnHeader" valign="top">
                172.24.*
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>

            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
    <xp:br></xp:br>


    <div id="container"></div>



    <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:

        // GET INFO FROM NETKEYS SESSIONSCOPE AND SAVE IT TO JSON FORMAT
        sessionScope.netKeys = (sessionScope.netKeys || new java.util.HashMap());
        var netKeysJSON:com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject = 
          new com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject();

        var arr_key = sessionScope.netKeys.keySet();
        //print ("Printing netKeys");
        for (x in arr_key) {
            print(x +" > "+ sessionScope.netKeys[x]);
            netKeysJSON.put(x, sessionScope.netKeys[x]);
        }
        sessionScope.netKeysJSON = "";
        sessionScope.netKeysJSON = netKeysJSON.toString();


        }]]></xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[

        // READ ALL JSON ENTRIES AND CHECK SPECIFIC CHECKBOXES!
        myVar = '#{javascript:sessionScope.get("netKeysJSON")}';

        //print("Printing JSON");
        if (myVar.length > 0) {

            var arr = $.parseJSON(myVar);

            for( key in arr ) {
                console.log(key +" >> "+ arr[key]);

                //$("label[for='"+ key +"']").remove();
                $("input[id='"+ key +"']").prop('checked', true);
                loadNetsInfo(arr[key], key, true);
            }

        }

]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:view>
```

ajax page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">


    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
    sessionScope.netKeys = (sessionScope.netKeys || new java.util.HashMap());

    var act = param.get("act");
    var ip  = param.get("ip");
    var id  = param.get("id");

    /**
     * problem!
    **/
    if (ip == null || ip.length == 0 ||
        id == null || id.length == 0 ||  
        act == null || act.length == 0) 
    {
        writer.write("ERROR: No parameters specified.");
        writer.endDocument();
        return false;
    }

    // NO PROBLEM!

    // REMOVE
    if (act == "rem") {
        sessionScope.netKeys.remove(id);
        print("Removed "+ id +" from netKeys");
    }

    // LIST ALL
    else if (act == "list") {
    print("List of all items in HashMap ("+ sessionScope.netKeys.size() +")");
        var arr_key = sessionScope.netKeys.keySet();
        for (x in arr_key) {
            print(x +" > "+ sessionScope.netKeys[x]);
            //netKeysJSON.put(x, sessionScope.netKeys[x]);
        }
    }

    // WIPE ALL
    else if (act == "wipe") {
        sessionScope.netKeys = null;
        sessionScope.remove("netKeys");
        print("Array netKeys wiped.");
    }

    // ADD + VIEW
    else if (act == "view") {
        var output = "<table style=\"display: inline-table; width: 150px;\" id=\"subnet_"+ ip +"\" border='1'><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><b>"+ ip +"</b></td></tr>";

        sessionScope.netKeys.put(id, ip);
        //writer.write("*** "+ sessionScope.netKeys.get(id));

        // start getting info now...

        var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("", "***HIDDEN***.nsf");
        var doc:NotesDocument = null;


        ////////////////
        // subnet info
        ////////////////        
        //var formula:string = "Subject=\"" + requestScope.query + "\"";
        var formula:string = "Form = \"SubnetInfo\" & subnet = \""+ ip +"\"";
        var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = db.search(formula);
        //print(formula);

        if (dc.getCount() > 0) {
            doc = dc.getFirstDocument();
            var desc = doc.getMIMEEntity("description").getContentAsText();
            output += "<tr><td colspan=\"2\">"+ desc +"</td></tr>";
        }

        else {
            print ("ID "+ id +" & IP "+ ip +" doesn't have any info. Removing entry.");
            sessionScope.netKeys.remove(id);
        }

        ////////////////
        // ip's
        ////////////////
        var formula:string = "Form = \"IP\" & Net = \""+ ip +"\"";
        dc = db.search(formula);
        //print("dc count: "+ dc.getCount());

        doc = dc.getFirstDocument();

        while (doc != null) {
            var docURL = "NetsSingle.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=" + doc.getNoteID();
            //print(docURL);
            output += "<tr><td><a href=\""+ docURL +"\">"+ doc.getItemValueInteger("IP") +"</a></td><td>"+ ((doc.getItemValueString("inUseFor").length == 0) ? "&nbsp" : doc.getItemValueString("inUseFor")) +"</td></tr>";

            doc = dc.getNextDocument();
        }


        output += "</table>";
        writer.write(output);

    } // end: ADD + VIEW


writer.endDocument();
}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>

</xp:view>
```

ajax function call (javascript that runs when checking/unchecking checkbox):

```
function loadNetsInfo(ip, id, add) {
    var url = "_netsGetInfo.xsp?act="+ ((add == true) ? "view" : "rem") +"&ip="+ ip +"&id="+ id;

    //alert(url);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){

        if (add == true) {
            $("#container").append(result);
        }
        else {
            $("[id='subnet_"+ ip +"']").remove();
        }

    }});
}
```

**SOLUTION**

As @stwissel suggested on his reply to my question, his is what I've did that fixed everything. With that, I've also optimized and replaced javascript, which fastened the code process!

faces-config.xml (open through Package Explorer). Notice, that I've tried to create its own class (which you could do to extend HashMap), but I didn't needed that, so the only logical and simple way is just to add session scoped managed bean of type HashMap.

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>checkBoxStatus</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

On my main page, all checkboxes were now handled by managed bean and looked like that:

```
<xp:checkBox text="10.5.33" id="checkBox3" value="#{checkBoxStatus['10.5.33']}"></xp:checkBox>
```

So the value is true or false, which means checked or not. So HashMap looks like

```
checkBoxStatus['10.5.33'] = true;
checkBoxStatus['10.1.31'] = true;
checkBoxStatus['192.168.1'] = false;
checkBoxStatus['10.6.207'] = true;
```

The code above simply checks or unchecks the checkboxes depending on bean we created in faces.

Now, instead of creating JSON string from session array and then recieveing info from server using ajax call, I just loop through my checkboxes where their id starts/ends with checkBox:

```
<xp:this.script><![CDATA[
// GO THROUGH ALL CHECKED ELEMENTS, CALL _netsGetInfo
$( "input[id*='checkBox']:checked" ).each(function( index ) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var ip = $("label[for='"+ id +"']").text();
        var ip_clean = ip.replace(/\./g, "_");

        console.log( index + ": " + id +", "+ ip +", "+ ip_clean );
        loadNetsInfo(ip, id, true);
});
]]></xp:this.script>
```

The _netsGetInfo.xsp doesn't manage any session HashMap as it did before.

Case closed, everything works AS CHARM!

Big thank you to stwissel and stackoverflow community. IBM Developerworks community sadly didn't helped at all.

Comment: It would help a lot if we could actually see the code that you're running - it's likely that the problem is in there.

Comment: @Chris I've updated my entry with the code. thank you for swift reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a server round trip on change of a checkbox isn't recommended. Here is what I would do: bind your checkboxes to a managed bean. E.g call it checkboxstatus. Then your checkbox has value="#{checkboxstatus['someid']}" the binding will make sure values get updated correctly. 
Then you can decide if each change of a box gets send back or you just send it back on the action your users want to perform. 
The bean can be a default HashMap